# Shortcode Works for Logged in Users but Not Working for Guest

Tags: php, plugin-development, shortcode

I've added my shortcode to a Wordpress page and it appears that the shortcode doesn't run unless the page is viewed by someone logged into an account. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MGC
Description: A plugin to integrate software
Author: Mike Grossman
Version: 0.1
*/

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/aweber_api/aweber_api.php');
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wlm_api/class-api-methods.php' );
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wlm_api/wlmapiclass.php');

$member_registration_results = array();

add_action('admin_menu', 'mgc_plugin_setup_menu'); //load menu bar on the admin panela and run the function 

function mgc_plugin_setup_menu(){

    add_menu_page( 'MGC Plugin Page', 'MGC Plugin', 'manage_options', 'mgc-plugin', 'mgc_page_output'); 
}

function mgc_page_output(){

echo "MGC Plugin Activated!";
}

//Capture the $_POST data

function wpd_post_parse() {

    $string = 'wp hook: ' . var_dump($_POST) . "\r\n";

    $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';     

    file_put_contents($fileName, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}

function mgc_init(){

   $htmlStr = 'Hello World!' . "\r\n";

   $fileName = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';

   file_put_contents($fileName, $htmlStr, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

   //do_action( 'wpd_post_parse' );

}

//add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_post_parse' );

add_shortcode('mgc','mgc_init'); //put this shortcode [mgc] on page in Wordpress 
?>
```

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by clearing the browser cache and using Chrome incognito mode when necessary.